# Can I remove the launcher tooltip delay?

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

Ubuntu 11.10 provides a small delay for displaying the tool-tip when hovering over items in the launcher. This, oddly enough, gives the impression of a sluggish desktop.

Is there anyway to disable this? I can't seem to find any option to do so in ccsm.

Relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/804021

Answer (score 2):

No, I don’t think there’s any way to change the tooltip delay. So let’s see what’s the resolution of the bug report.

UPDATE: Tooltip delay has been removed.